# Admob for iPhone/iPad

Tags: objective-c, iphone, admob

Can you explain me please in short how to start with admob? I registered, but can't find the download link for the sdk. Any good tutorials? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using AdMob directly, you can try [AdWhirl](http://www.adwhirl.com/)

Comment: Yes, but I have a request to use AdMob... That's the bad side.

Comment: definitely u can use admob from adwhirl. there should not be any problem.

Comment: but it's a bit overhead, isn't it?

Comment: if u consider the benefits, then its not. with no change in client code, u can add multiple networks, change their ad percentage etc. etc. and the client code is simple. u only need to set up an adwhirl view and some keys. thats all. even if u r planning to use only admob, then still very little work is required which is more or less same if u use standalone admob library. and obviously u dont want to add only one network. in case of adwhirl, when u configure multiple ad network, if one fails then adwhirl supplies u ad from another network.

Comment: another key point is if u update the iphone code, then it will need to go through apple approval process which is time consuming. so its important to configure multiple ad network without changing the iphone code. obviously if u use one network always (which is unlikely, at least now iAd is in action), then this is not a benefit at all.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the answers. :) You convinced me. I will use adwhirl.